# use function on multiple columns

Tags: r, function, measure

I've created this function to calculate mean, median and SD:

```
f1<- function(x) c(mean= round(mean(x),2), median= round(median(x),2), sd= round(sd(x),2))
```

I want to use it for multiple columns (names of columns: domain 1, domain2, domain3, total)

I want to know how to use the function, and would you recommend a better way than using a function to present mean, median and sd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to apply `f1` function to multiple columns.

```
f1<- function(x) c(mean= round(mean(x),2), median= round(median(x),2), sd= round(sd(x),2))
cols <- c('mpg', 'cyl')
sapply(mtcars[cols], f1)

#         mpg  cyl
#mean   20.09 6.19
#median 19.20 6.00
#sd      6.03 1.79
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(c(mpg, cyl), list(mean = mean, sd = sd, median = median)))

#  mpg_mean   mpg_sd mpg_median cyl_mean   cyl_sd cyl_median
#1 20.09062 6.026948       19.2   6.1875 1.785922          6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(slt(mtcars, 1:2), FUN = function(x) c(Mean = fmean(x), 
      Median = fmedian(x), SD = fsd(x)))
#            mpg      cyl  
#Mean   20.090625 6.187500
#Median 19.200000 6.000000
#SD      6.026948 1.785922
```